# Retagging: Coding style? Conventions? Practices?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

Tag proposal number 2:

Merge [code-style](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-style) and [coding-conventions](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-conventions) into [coding-style](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-style)

Upvote if you agree, downvote if you disagree, or answer if there are additional considerations.

Comment: If/when done, we can also create the synonym from coding-conventions to code-style

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Agreed.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver I don't see the need to make a synonym unless [tag:coding-conventions] starts appearing again.